# How to get the path of a Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the path location of my wordpress plugin. I don't mind if I have to get it via code or via checking the sources on my google devtools. I tried doing it via my sources on devtool but didn't find it. I'm new to PHP and WP so I don't know much how scoping works.

When I go to devtools I don't see my plugins folder but the plugin is working and When I go to the admin console, I do see my plug in activated.

[image: wordpress pluging]

Comment: There are two core functions that might help you, [`plugin_dir_path`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) and [`plugin_dir_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_url/). The former gets the file system absolute path to the plugin and the latter gets a fully-qualified URL. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Please share more details - why not use `__DIR__`? In which case should this be relevant in any case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your chrome dev tools won't mirror your local file structure. It's showing folders where assets are being loaded from. If your plugin doesn't load any CSS / JS, it won't be listed.

To get your plugin's directory URL, add the following code:

```
echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
```

If you want the path instead, use:

```
echo plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
```

Either line must be used from within the plugin.

Docs:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_url/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome dev - go to Sources and then expand the wp-content folder, and then the plugins folder.

Wordpress plugins are usually found at this path:
https://your_domain.com/wp-content/plugins/the_plugin_folder

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have attached an image showing my dev tools but I don't see my plugins folder

Comment: That does not look like a good hint - why should anybody load such data over HTTP from within PHP? Why not use the file system, without any network access?

Comment: He didn't say anything about loading data originally - only wanting the path, with a mention of devtools.  Perhaps the question wasn't clear to begin with.